# Program only reads the first line in the file

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file which contains a name on a line followed by numbers on the second line. 3rd line is a name and 4th is numbers and so on.

I tested it on main method. For example my file contains the name "Bobby" and his telno is 123456, when I run lookUpEntry("Bobby"), I should get his telno returned to me. This works if the name "Bobby" is the first name on the file. If it isn't the first, the program doent seem to recognize the name and returns me a null. Been cracking at it and unable to see the problem. Please advice if you see any. Thanks.

```
//DirectoryEntry is a class and contains a String name and String telno along with set/ get methods for them. 
private DirectoryEntry[] theDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[100];
private int size = 0;

public void loadData(String sourceName) {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(sourceName));

            while (in.hasNextLine()){
                String name = in.nextLine();
                String telno = in.nextLine();
                theDirectory[size] = new DirectoryEntry(name, telno);
                size++;
            }
            in.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }

public String lookUpEntry(String name) {
        find(name);
        if (find(name) >= 0){
            return theDirectory[find(name)].getNumber();
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

public int find(String name){
        for (int x=0; x < theDirectory.length; x++){
            if (theDirectory[x].getName().equals(name)){
                return x;
            }
            else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return  -1;
    }
```

The following is the file content:

Alan A

123456

Bobby B

234567

Charlie C

456789

Daniel D

567891

Eric E

787454

Comment: To start I would point out that you are checking if the file has a next line, but then you are getting the next two lines without checking if that second line exists.

Comment: What about CaSe? Or whitespace? See what happens when you `.equalsIgnoreCare(name.trim());`.

Comment: Post the code where you call these methods and an example of the file to be read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your find method, you traverse the array, but you use an if, else block.  Basically, if the name you're looking for isn't at index 0, the code will jump to the else statement and return -1.

<del>EDIT: Wait sorry, I don't see you using the function in your main code anyway... Still something you should fix.</del>

EDIT 2: That's not your main method... Scratch that again...

Fixed code:

```
public int find(String name){
    for (int x=0; x < theDirectory.length; x++){
        if (theDirectory[x].getName() != null && theDirectory[x].getName().equals(name)){
            return x;
        }
    }
    return  -1;
}
```

Comment: He is using the find() method three times inside his lookUpEntry() method.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that.  I thought that first method was his main method.

Comment: Silly mistake and ended up staring at the screen over an hr for that. Tnks.

Answer (score 1):

get ride of the else statement in find. It is returning -1 after checking the first time. find should be:

```
public int find(String name){
    for (int x=0; x < theDirectory.length; x++){
        if (theDirectory[x].getName() != null && theDirectory[x].getName().equals(name)){
            return x;
        }
    }
    return  -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning -1 from your `public int find(String name)` method if what you are looking for is not at the first element

Here's what it should look like

```
public int find(String name) {

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        if (theDirectory[i].getName() != null && theDirectory[i].getName().equals(name))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```